# Tools to develop user interface of a web application/ website ?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which prototyping tools?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools)

What are the good tools to develop user interface of a web application/ website ?

I know to use Illustrator but I doubt that is the best & easiest way to design GUIs for websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use photoshop to make the UI-Elmenets.

For Icons:There are a resource called the noun project..it contains hundreds of icons.
Some icons on the web are made of real pictures..with some playing in photoshop.
Some of them are based on fonts..like pictos..etc.

For UI-Elements such like scroll bars,buttons,on/off buttons,check boxes..etc..Get UI freebies(in the format of PS or Ai)and then make the change you want on them.

Anyway..Making UI-Elements on your own is not an easy task.Really needs hard work and attention to details make the UI Elements Pexil Perfected :)

ref:
Self Experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Balsamiq's tools](http://balsamiq.com/) in the past and can heartily recommend them. They're great for designing the layout and user interface of a site, but not for designing the overall look and feel of a site.

There's also [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) which a bit more geared towards designing the look and feel of a site in addition to the UI.

Comment: aren't there any good *free* tools ?

Comment: Inkscape and GIMP are decent Open Source image/illustration apps.