# What is a good tool to prototype Windows 10 programs?

Tags: gui-design, design, desktop-application, prototype

I am a user experience designer who is recently assigned to work on a Windows 10 desktop application. I am not sure with what tool I should use for prototyping and illustrating the interactions to designers.

The engineers suggest me to use Blend for GUI prototyping. Anyone of you has any experience with this tool? Or is there a better way to communicate my design?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This isn't really answerable beyond "a good tool to use is one that you are familiar and comfortable with". The engineers suggested Blend because it's a MS product. It does have some integration with Visual Studio so there may be *some* benefit to that, but it all depends on what your engineers need/want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a tool recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Most wireframing / prototyping tools aren't platform specific. They're a blank canvas and you can use them for any platform. There's a significant group of mobile-specific tools which you can't use for desktop sites and apps, but beyond that I don't think there's any difference. An overview of some of the tools can be found [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools).