# Most used UX tools

Tags: tools, prototype, wireframe

Which is the best tool out there for creating prototypes and wireframes ? I am going to purchase a new computer and was wondering whether i should choose the Windows OS or iOS - given the fact that there are many tools that work seamlessly with Mac.

Currently I am using the trial version of UXPin and Balsamiq. Thanks!

Comment: you can use a combination of sketch + craft + invision

Comment: This isn't really the place for product recommendations, I'm afraid. Answers will get outdated pretty quickly. You can have a look at [this older question though](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools?rq=1) which covers off several options.

Comment: Sorry about that @JonW

Answer (score 2):

When I started learning how to do wire-framing to one of the app that I was designing " Healthy eating for diabetic patients" I tried several application. I am using windows and I can summarize my experience as follow :

**Using windows**

- You can use [Balsamique] for Low-Fid wirframe or sketching out an Idea of the app. [1](https://balsamiq.com/)
- Photoshop CC for High-Fid, mockup of the app. I love Photoshop since they have already added artboard feature which is meant for App/web Designers. Also Photoshop cc helps you to export your final work to Invision to do your Usability testing and share your prototype with users.
- illustrator : You can use it to create User-Flow and Tasks-Flow of your app.
- By the end of this year, Adobe will release a new tool called " [Adobe Experience Design CC](http://www.adobe.com/products/experience-design.html)" They have already released A beta-version on Mac-OS.

**Using Mac-OS**

I am not a Mac-OS user, thus I will share what I did. I installed Mac-OS on virtual box so that I can use [Sketch 3.](https://www.sketchapp.com/) It's great application made easy for non-designers and you can get your Low-Fid and High-Fid design in matter of days. It also helps you to create your own custom icons and many more. I love the community this software has and in there you can find alot of free resources and create idea of different application.

If you want more information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Every tool has its advantages and disadvantages. I suggest you visit this [site](http://www.cooper.com/prototyping-tools), and choose from there. There you can choose your tool depending on your project needs, and it has great reviews of the wireframe tools.

Basically, [Balsamique](https://balsamiq.com/), [invisionApp](https://www.invisionapp.com/) are the most famous in my opinion.