# Which Free Wireframe and Mockup Application do you recommend?

Tags: mockup, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which prototyping tools?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools)

Things I would like:

- Open source
- No restrictions
- Simple and powerful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like the answers to these questions:

- [What are some great web-based prototyping tools?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/375/what-are-some-great-web-based-prototyping-tools)
- [Which prototyping tools?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Free? Most of the apps listed in this [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/375/what-are-some-great-web-based-prototyping-tools) have a free account, but you'll have to pay for more space/users/etc.

Real free are [Pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pencil/) and Google Draw using [this stencil](http://mortenjust.com/2010/04/19/a-wireframe-kit-for-google-drawings/).